# server side php email validation not working

Tags: php

I am practicing PHP and I created a signup form that performs client-side validation and also server-side. Javascript works perfectly and performs client-side but I removed all the javascript to see whether server-side works or not but it is not working and it submits the form without showing my errors.

Here is the Server-side code:

```
if($_POST)
{

    $query = "SELECT `email` FROM `users` where email =" . "'" . $_POST['Email'] . "'";

    $result = mysqli_query($db,$query);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if($_POST['Email'] == $row['email'])
    {

        $error .= "This Email address is already registered with us";

    }

    if($error != "")
    {

        $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><p>There were error(s) in your form:</p>' . $error . '</div>';

    }
}
```

Here is the form Code:

```
<form method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Email">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email" name="Email" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `if($_POST['Email'] == $row)` - $row is an _array_, it makes little sense to compare that to the input value - if anything, this would need to be `$row['email']`. But this comparison makes little sense to begin - you already demanded this in the WHERE clause of your query. No point in making the same comparison twice. You should be checking the number of returned rows here.

Comment: `$error !== null` please. Otherwise it passes for empty strings, zero, false..

Comment: $error !== null tried this still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Executing a SELECT query will always result in a array, so $row is an array and the email has to be checked like this

```php
if($_POST['Email'] == $row['email'])
```

Logging the variable $row will give you more information.

There are other ways to check if the query found something, look:
https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: Try to var_dump($row); and look at it's contents

Comment: obviously var_dump($row) is null when I submit an empty form! but if I enter email which is already in database var_dump returns the email! I also have code which checks whether the email field is empty or not that also doesn't work when I submit an empty form!

Comment: if $row['email'] returns the email in the database, then what doesn't work?
For checking if there already is an entry in the database I suggest if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)

But the check on top should work. I wouldn't make sense that $_POST['Email'] work is actually getting getting data when used in a mysql query but returns false when you check against the returned DB data.